# Stacked Conditional-RNN (LSTM) layers with multi-step prediction output with different timesteps as input

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am building a stacked LSTM time prediction model, with 299 household's energy consumption data. Together with the temporal energy consumption data, I have the location of every household. I want to use Philippe Remy's implementation of conditional RNN's, the ConditionalRecurrent layer, which is useful if you have time series data with external inputs that do not depend on time. However, it seems to me that the output's timesteps has to be the same as the input's timesteps? I.e. training data number of timesteps has to be equal to the predicted timesteps. But, I want to use a lookback period of 1 week to predict 1 day in advance. Does anybody have any idea how to do this using ConditionalRecurrent layer? https://pypi.org/project/cond-rnn/

Here is a sample of my code:

```
def define_model_4(X_train, y_train, num_steps_ahead=24,
               location_data=customer_locations):
  num_samples = X_train.shape[0] # 753 sequences
  input_dim = X_train.shape[2] # number of households, 299
  num_locations = 2 # num_conditions, 2 locational inputs per household
  time_steps = X_train.shape[1] # number of timesteps per sequence, 1 week look back

  i = Input(shape=[time_steps, input_dim], name='time_series_input')
  c = Input(shape=[num_locations], name='location_input')

 # layer 1
  x = ConditionalRecurrent(LSTM(units=128, activation='relu',
                            return_sequences=True, name='cond_rnn_0'))([i, c])
  x = Dropout(0.2)(x)

  # layer 2
  x = ConditionalRecurrent(LSTM(units=128, activation='relu',
                            return_sequences=True, name='cond_rnn_1'))([x, c])
  x = Dropout(0.2)(x)

  # layer 3
  x = ConditionalRecurrent(LSTM(units=128, activation='relu',
                            return_sequences=False, name='cond_rnn_2'))([x, c])
  x = Dropout(0.2)(x)

  # output layer
  x = RepeatVector(num_steps_ahead)(x) # num_steps_ahead=y_train.shape[1]: 24 hours ahead
  x = TimeDistributed(Dense(y_train.shape[2]))(x) # for every household

  # build model
  model_4 = Model(inputs=[i, c], outputs=[x])

  # compile model
  optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.001, clipnorm=1.0)
  model_4.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mae')

  return model_4

# flow for model
def run_test_flow_model_4(x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val,
              x_test = X_test, y_test=y_test, epochs=150,
                      location_data=customer_locations):

  # define model
  model_4 = define_model_4(x_train, y_train, location_data=customer_locations) 

  # define callbacks
  early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=40,
                           restore_best_weights=True)

  # save best model
  model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('model_4.h5', monitor='val_loss',
                   save_best_only=True, verbose=1) # save best model and print
                                                   # saved epoch

  # fit model
  history_4 = model_4.fit([x_train, customer_locations], y_train, epochs=epochs,
                  batch_size=32, validation_data=([x_val, location_data], y_val),
                  callbacks=[model_checkpoint, early_stopping])

  # learning curves

  summary_diagnostics(history_4, 'model_4') # own function to get training and validation loss per epoch


run_test_flow_model_4(X_train, y_train,
          X_val,  y_val,
          x_test = X_test, y_test = y_test,
          epochs=150, location_data=customer_locations)
```

---

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 3>()
1 # # run model 4 on all households in parallel
2
----> 3 run_test_flow_model_4(X_train, y_train,
4               X_val,  y_val,
5               x_test = X_test, y_test = y_test,

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in _check_data_cardinality(data)
1846             )
1847         msg += "Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples."
-> 1848         raise ValueError(msg)
1849
1850

ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
x sizes: 762, 299
y sizes: 762
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.